# "Load" texts from Plist file and use it(Xcode)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, macos

I have 4 UIbuttons and one UILabel.I want to do 4 words (from plist file )random shown on 4 buttons(one button has one word) and one word shown on label(that have the same name  of the word on the button). How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your plist is called `words.plist` and that you have an array of 4 `UIButtons`

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray * words = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Now you have all the possible words in the `words` array. At this point we need 4 unique random indices, which basically means to take the starting 4 elements of the array after randomly shuffling it. We'll use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6153873/846273) answer.

```
for (int i = words.count - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    int r = arc4random_uniform(i);
    [words exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:r];
}
```

Now that we have a randomly shuffled array of words, we just take the first 4 elements and assign them to the buttons. It would look something like:

```
for (int j = 0; j < buttons.count; j++) {
    UIButton * button = [buttons objectAtIndex:j];
    button.titleLabel.text = [words objectAtIndex:j];
}
```

Finally we assign a word to the label, randomly choosing an index between the one we used for the buttons:

```
yourLabel.text = [words objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(buttons.count)];
```

This solution works with an arbitrary number of buttons, it's guaranteed to be efficient due to the shuffling algorithm (which is definitely better than checking for already generated indices) and the random generation is not biased thanks to the use of `arc4random_uniform`

Comment: Thanks but I have crash in iphone simulator:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NsRangeException', reason NSMutableArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'

Comment: You are right, I got the indexes wrong. The loop for shuffling the words has to go from words.count - 1 to 0. I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Move the contents of the PLIST file into an array.

```
NSArray *words = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Randomly find a number.

```
int randInt = arc4random() % 10;
```

Change `10` to the total number of words in the PLIST.

You can now select the random word out of the array.

```
NSString *random = [words objectAtIndex:randInt];
```

You have one random word. Find another random number (check to make sure it is not the same as the previous one) and then choose the next word out of the `words` array.